# Setup signal and slot before moving Worker object to QThread in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qobject

In Qt/PyQt, I used to make threading using a Worker class and a QThread.

```
self.worker = Worker()
self.thread = QThread()

worker.moveToThread(thread)
setup_signal_slot_with_main_object()

// start 
thread.start()
```

I must place *setup_signal_slot_with_main_object()* after *moveToThread()*. But I have a complex worker. In *Worker.__ init__()*, it creates many QObjects and connects internal signals and slots. I don't want to create a method which makes all connections and calls *worker.setup_signal_slot()* after *worker->moveToThread(&thread)* because Worker contains many child QObjects and each QObject can make signal/slot in its constructor.

In Qt/C++, I can make signal/slot connection in worker's constructor. But in PyQt, slot will not run in new thread.

This is an example with a Worker contains a QTimer

```py
import sys
import signal
import threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer, QCoreApplication, QThread
import datetime


class Worker(QObject):
    timeChanged = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)

        # I want to make connection at here
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.main_process)

    def start(self):
        # self.timer.timeout.connect(self.main_process)
        self.timer.start()
        print('Worker thread {}: Start timer'.format(threading.get_ident()))

    # this method still run in main thread
    def main_process(self):
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('Worker thread {}: {}'.format(threading.get_ident(), timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S')))
        self.timeChanged.emit(timestamp)


class WorkerThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.emitter = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.emitter.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.emitter.start)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.emitter.deleteLater)
        self.emitter.timeChanged.connect(self.show_time)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.quit()
            self.thread.wait()
            print('Exit thread')

    def show_time(self, timestamp):
        print('Main   thread {}: {}'.format(threading.get_ident(), timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S')))


def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('Quit')
    app.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: None)
    timer.start(500)

    print('Main    thread {}'.format(threading.get_ident()))
    emitter = WorkerThread()
    emitter.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In Worker, timer timeout will call main_process in main thread. I can move *self.timer.timeout.connect(self.main_process)* into method *worker.start()*. But as I have said above, I still want to place internal  signal/slot in its constructor.
Could anyone suggest me a solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the methods to be invoked in the same thread where the receiver uses the [`pyqtSlot()`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) decorator, if you don't do it then it will be called in the sender's thread.

```py
import sys
import signal
import threading
import datetime

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer, QCoreApplication, QThread, pyqtSlot


class Worker(QObject):
    timeChanged = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.main_process)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()
        print("Worker thread {}: Start timer".format(threading.get_ident()))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def main_process(self):
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(
            "Worker thread {}: {}".format(
                threading.get_ident(), timestamp.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S")
            )
        )
        self.timeChanged.emit(timestamp)


class WorkerThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.emitter = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.emitter.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.emitter.start)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.emitter.deleteLater)
        self.emitter.timeChanged.connect(self.show_time)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.quit()
            self.thread.wait()
            print("Exit thread")

    @pyqtSlot(object)
    def show_time(self, timestamp):
        print(
            "Main   thread {}: {}".format(
                threading.get_ident(), timestamp.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S")
            )
        )


def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("Quit")
    app.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: None)
    timer.start(500)

    print("Main    thread {}".format(threading.get_ident()))
    emitter = WorkerThread()
    emitter.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
Main    thread 140175719339648
Worker thread 140175659480832: Start timer
Worker thread 140175659480832: 26-07-2019 04-39-42
Main   thread 140175719339648: 26-07-2019 04-39-42
Worker thread 140175659480832: 26-07-2019 04-39-43
Main   thread 140175719339648: 26-07-2019 04-39-43
Worker thread 140175659480832: 26-07-2019 04-39-44
Main   thread 140175719339648: 26-07-2019 04-39-44
Worker thread 140175659480832: 26-07-2019 04-39-45
Main   thread 140175719339648: 26-07-2019 04-39-45
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I misunderstand that any python methods are slot. I should add @pyqtSlot to all my slots especially for multi-threading program.